# How to swap adjacent corners?

Tags: optimization, rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I want to swap adjacent corners of U layer, the only thing I care is:

- position of other 6 corners.

I **don't** care:

- orientation of all corners
- position of all edges
- orientation of all edges

The goal is put all 8 corners to their correct position (exclude orientation, I'll rotate them next step), any other piece doesn't matter at all.

I have found some solutions, but they are too complex, they also try to minimize the changes made to other pieces, but I don't care at all. I want to find simpler solution, or the most simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This takes 7 moves, and cannot be done in less (I checked by computer).

Here are all the optimal ways to swap the two UF corners using only moves of the U, R, and F faces:

```
U F U' F' R' F' R
U' F' U F R U R'
R U' R' U' F' U F
R U' R' F' U' F U
R' F R U F U' F'
R' F R F U F' U'
F U F' U' R' F' R
F' U' F U R U R'
```